# I don't know why the installation doesn't finish when i use yarn

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

When i use yarn the installation doesn't finish like in the github reprisotory https://fresh-app.github.io/fresh-react-app.html#result and also it doesn't create src file and gitgnore ect just the node modules and the json package
here is my cmd:

```
PS C:\Users\ANAS> yarn create react-app fresh-app2
yarn create v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "create-react-app@5.0.1" with binaries:
      - create-react-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\ANAS\fresh-app2.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
warning react-scripts > css-minimizer-webpack-plugin > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
warning "react-scripts > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 761 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
//I deleted the dependencies just to minimize the code (they are the same as in the link) 
Done in 41.54s.
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete package.json.lock and try installing again

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error "yarn: command not found", install the yarn package globally by running npm install -g yarn and restart your terminal. If the command fails, run it with sudo and make sure the correct PATH is set in your system's environment variable.